Disabling Spring boot actuator endpoint HTTP request logging
I am struggling with an issue regarding spring boot actuator logging. I have an application integrated with spring boot actuator and Prometheus as monitoring system. I have enabled the /actuator/prometheus endpoint in application.properties file. The scrape interval in prometheus.yml is 2s. Thus, every 2s GET requests are made to the application and it gets logged in the application logs and therefore spams the log file. I want to disable it someway.
If i turn off logging.level.org.springframework.web then I wont be receiving HTTP request logs for every other endpoints. I don't want that behavior, I simply want to disable the logs for the actuator endpoints and only in case they return 200 OK in response.
I have seen some solutions suggesting creation of separate Filter Bean methods which will rule-in/out the required endpoints. But I don't want the application to be URL specific because if tomorrow the base URL for Prometheus changes then I will have to update it everywhere in the code. Rather i want something simple configuration like logging.level.org.springframework.actuate.endpoint.prometheus=off which will help maintaining the application easily.
NP: I have already tried using logging.level.org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus=off/error logging.level.org.springframework.actuate.endpoint.prometheus=off/error but these didn't work.
Kindly suggest if anyone has solved this issue.
Sample spam log:
# TYPE system_cpu_usage gauge
s (truncated)...]
22-05-2024 12:39:55.387 [http-nio-8082-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.logResult:1131 - Completed 200 OK
22-05-2024 12:39:57.376 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.core.log.LogFormatUtils.traceDebug:91 - GET "/actuator/prometheus", parameters={}
22-05-2024 12:39:57.425 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters:255 - Using 'text/plain;version=0.0.4;charset=utf-8;q=0.3', given [application/openmetrics-text;version=1.0.0;q=0.5, application/openmetrics-text;version=0.0.1;q=0.4, text/plain;version=0.0.4;q=0.3, */*;q=0.2] and supported [text/plain;version=0.0.4;charset=utf-8]
22-05-2024 12:39:57.425 [http-nio-8082-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.core.log.LogFormatUtils.traceDebug:91 - Writing ["# HELP system_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" for the whole system
# TYPE system_cpu_usage gauge
s (truncated)...]


First question is why do you even log those at all? They pollute your logging. Your only option is writing a filter for your logging provider to filter these out.

The purpose for logging other required endpoints is to track when a request is actually coming in and when response is actually going out. As my application deals with financial transactions so I have to check them frequently for monitoring delays in transactions.

It isn't I'm questioning your usecase, I'm questioning your use of enabling DEBUG logging for that instead of writing a dedicated component for this. You shouldn't run DEBUG in production environments.
